# Query nested arrays of subdocuments

Tags: arrays, mongodb, typescript, subdocument

EDIT: The query should not user the '&" characters. Those or for updates.

ANSWER: Courtesy of Gibbs

```
correct: 
const result : any = await mongoose.model('Events').update(
    {
        _id: eventId,
        "groups._id": groupId,
        "groups.users._id": userId
    },
```

```
incorrect:
const result: any = await mongoose.model('Events').findOne(
    {
        _id: eventId,
        "groups._id": "5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e",
        "groups.$.users": { _id: '5f270877b4942d2528885dbd' }
    })
    // OR:
    {
        _id: eventId,
        "groups._id": "5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e",
        "groups.$.users._id" : '5f270877b4942d2528885dbd',  
    })
```

With only the first two predicates,(`eventId` and groups `[$_id]`) it returns the event. But the third breaks.

Does anybody know why this returns null (object ids are copied directly from the db)
Thanks!

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f270416e7964b20d6f8953d"),
    "lastRounds": [],
    "name": "EpicFest",
    "start": 1596392488896.0,
    "end": 1596392500896.0,
    "groups": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e"),
        "name": "Vossius",
        "users": [
          {
            "created": 1596393590778.0,
            "sessionId": null,
            "feedBack": {
              "messagesSent": 0,
              "messagesSentLiked": 0,
              "messagesReceived": 0,
              "messagesReceivedLiked": 0,
              "userFeedbackReceived": [],
              "chatFeedbackReceived": [],
              "_id": ObjectId("5f270877b4942d2528885dbe")
            },
            "_id": ObjectId("5f270877b4942d2528885dbd"),
            "image": "someAvatr",
            "name": "hans",
            "groupId": "5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e",
            "results": []
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f270416e7964b20d6f8953f"),
        "users": [],
        "name": "Ignatius"
      }
    ],
    "results": [],
    "theses": [],
    "rounds": 10,
    "schedule": [],
    "__v": 4
}
```

Comment: Can you add sample document structure also?

Comment: Yes, I've added the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mongo Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DPSlbt3ogMZ)

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: ObjectId("5f270416e7964b20d6f8953d"),
  "groups._id": ObjectId("5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e"),
  "groups.users._id": ObjectId("5f270877b4942d2528885dbd")
})
```

You tried to use String `"5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e"`. It should be `ObjectId`

You can use `.` notation to access a nested element or `$elemMatch`

Comment: Thanks! I'm using TypeScript so I can't use ObjectId(id) without 'new' which breaks things (but strings work) . But as you pointed out I had  to lose the $ signs!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the aggregate pipeline to fetch based on the inner sub-document.

In the first match stage, filter by `eventId` and do a $elemMatch on the inner `groupId`.
Next, unwind the `group` and `groups.user`.

Post unwinding you will have a flat object structure that you can again apply filter upon and, just apply a match stage on `groups.user._id` now.

```
const pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            _id: eventId,
            groups: {
                $elemMatch: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f270416e7964b20d6f8953e')
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$groups'
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$groups.users'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            '$groups.users._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f270877b4942d2528885dbd')
        }
    }
];
const result: any = await mongoose.model('Events').aggregate(pipeline).exec();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, fortunately there was an easier answer!